# Java REGEX, remove two different type of comments from String

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have a text with two types of comments. The ones delimited by `%` and the ones that start with `/*` and end with `*/`. For instance:

> INPUT1: `Sarah was going out. % Remember she usually doesn't go out % It was very cold.`
>
> DESIRED_OUTPUT1: `Sarah was going out.  It was very cold.`
>
> INPUT2: `Sarah was going out. /* Remember she usually doesn't go out */ It was very cold.`
>
> DESIRED_OUTPUT2: `Sarah was going out.  It was very cold.`
>
> INPUT3: `Charles knocked on the door and a woman 
>   opened it. % Hmm, is this good... /* Not 
>   sure */ Perhaps this should happen in 
>   chapter 10 instead? % She looked at him.
>   - Yes?, she said.`
>
> DESIRED_OUTPUT3: `Charles knocked on the door and a woman 
>   opened it.  She looked at him.
>   - Yes?, she said.`
>
> INPUT4: `Charles knocked on the door and a woman 
>   opened it. % Hmm, is this good... /* Not 
>   sure to 100% */ Perhaps this should happen 
>   in chapter 10 instead? % She looked at him.
>   - Yes?, she said.`
>
> DESIRED_OUTPUT4: `Charles knocked on the door and a woman 
>   opened it.  */ Perhaps this should happen 
>   in chapter 10 instead?`

Basically, I would like that when encountering an opening comment mark, everything is removed until its respective closing comment mark (even if this means removing comment marks of the other type).

If a comment is opened, either with `%` or `/*`, but never closed, the comment is assumed to continue until the end of the text. However, if it is present just a closing mark of this kind `*/` (because the opener was inside another comment and hence removed), it should be left in the text.

Comment: I think Input 4 should result in `Charles knocked on the door and a woman 
  opened it.  */ Perhaps this should happen 
  in chapter 10 instead? % She looked at him.
  - Yes?, she said.`. You seem to want `.replaceAll("%[^%]*%|/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/","")`. There is a chance you need to make the last `%` optional though, `"%[^%]*%?|/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/"`.

Comment: Well, thank you for pointing that out. I forgot to mention that whether there is no closing mark (or just a closing one, since the opening was inside another comment and hence removed, like in this case) the mark should stay there. So Input/output 4 is correct.

Comment: So, acc. to what you say ("the mark should stay there"), the `% She looked at him.
  - Yes?, she said.` should not be removed in Input 4.

Comment: Well, you are right again. If a comment is opened, either with % or / *, but never closed, the comment is assumed to continue until the end of the text.

Comment: Aha, so you probably want `.replaceAll("%[^%]*%?|/\\*[^*]*(?:\\*(?!/)[^*]*)*(?:\\*/)?","")`

Comment: Thank you very much that is it! Could you briefly explain the logic behind it? I am not very expert in REGEX, but I would like to learn. Additionally, I would like to give you credit for the answer, but I think I can't do it to a comment. If you don't have time/do not want to put an answer, I can reply myself quoting you and giving you credit. You won't get points though! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
.replaceAll("%[^%]*%?|/\\*[^*]*(?:\\*(?!/)[^*]*)*(?:\\*/)?","")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rZDA6F/1/)

**Details**

- `%[^%]*%?` - `%...%` like comments with an optional trailing delimiter:

  - `%` - a `%` char
  - `[^%]*` - 0 or more chars other than `%`
  - `%?` - an optional `%` char
- `|` - or
- `/\*[^*]*(?:\*(?!/)[^*]*)*(?:\*/)?` - `/*...*/` like comments with an optional trailing delimiter:

  - `/\*` - `/*` string
  - `[^*]*` - 0 or more chars other than `*`
  - `(?:\*(?!/)[^*]*)*` - 0 or more occurrences of

    - `\*(?!/)` - a `*` not followed with `/`
    - `[^*]*` - 0 or more chars other than `*`
  - `(?:\*/)?` - an optional `*/` substring.